Select parent tags without selecting child tags
I'm working on an xml file, and ran into an issue I can't solve.
I have a series of tags I'm working with, that currently look like this:
<spells>
    <id-00001>
        <actions>
            <id-00001>
            </id-00001>
        </actions>
    </id-00001>
    <id-00002>
        <actions>
            <id-00001>
            </id-00001>
        </actions>
    </id-00002>
    <id-00003>
        <actions>
            <id-00001>
            </id-00001>
        </actions>
    </id-00003>
    <id-00001>
        <actions>
            <id-00001>
            </id-00001>
        </actions>
    </id-00001>
</spells>

Due to certain reasons, the outer tags go from id-00001 to id-000XX before looping back to 1. The end number is not consistent, sometimes it goes up to 00009, sometimes to 00029.
There are 601 total pairs of parent tags (open and close), and I need to number them sequentially from 00001 to 00601
The internal labels need to be ignored, since they are needed. There's usually 1 to 3 labels (00001 to 00003, or more if needed), but MUST be ignored.
I'm currently working on VSCode, but can adapt if needed.
I've tried selecting the tags with a regex, but this selects ALL tags, including children tags. Without this, any further testing is unnecessary, but I HAVE tried using Text Pastry in VSCode to autonumber and replace the tags.
Any ideas?

(1) It is a poor selection for XML element names. It would be much better to name them along the following: <city id="1"/>, <city id="2"/> (2) Regex is not applicable to XML.

I'm aware, unfortunately this is the data I was given, and I have to work with it. Also, regexes are applicable to search boxes in multiple IDEs :)

It is better to use native XML APIs: XPath, XQuery, XSLT, XSD, etc. Please edit your question, and add the desired output.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.


regex for xml/html is a BAD idea. 2)post a sample of how the result should look like. Questions must provide a [mcve].


Came up with an answer, I'll comment out the entire interior of the blocks by using multicursor selection in VSCode.
Crazy that people come up with rude and useless answers faster than I can come up with my own solutions.

Maybe you can add your solution, someone else might find it useful in the future. :)
